# Web page becomes unresponsive and crashes after few minutes

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

My web page becomes unresponsive, freezes and crashes after a few minutes when hosted on a server but work fine when running on localhost. 
I am getting api datas from a Flask Server(app)

The api engine is working on Flask and pulling data in form of JSON in every 1 second. Also updating google map marker based on the Lat Lon got from api

I expect that the web page don't freeze or becomes unresponsive

```js
var map_lat = 28.644800;
var map_lon = 77.216721;
var head = 0;
var ngUrl = "http://*******.com/";


function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function buttonFunctionPR(id) {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x1/");
  var response = httpGet(url + id);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = response['msg'];
}



hcFunOne = async() => {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x5/");
  var response = await httpGet(url);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  document.getElementById("alti").innerHTML = response['msg'];
  console.log(response['msg']);
  setTimeout(() => {
    hcFunOne();
  }, 1000)
}


hcFunTwo = async() => {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x6/");
  var response = await httpGet(url);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  var dataLB = response['msg2']
  var dataLB = dataLB.split("/");
  var htmlrespL = "Lattitude : <b>" + response['msg1'] + "</b>"
  var htmlrespB = "<b>Battery</b><hr class='hru hrusm'>Vlts : " + dataLB[0] + "<br>Level : " + dataLB[2] + " %&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; ";

  document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = htmlrespL;
  document.getElementById("batt").innerHTML = htmlrespB;

  window['map_lat'] = parseFloat(response['msg1']);
  setTimeout(() => {
    hcFunTwo();
  }, 1000)
}


hcFunThree = async() => {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x7/");
  var response = await httpGet(url);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  var htmlresp = "Longitude : <b>" + response['msg'] + "</b>"
  document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = htmlresp;

  window['map_lon'] = parseFloat(response['msg']);
  setTimeout(() => {
    hcFunThree();
  }, 1000)
}

hcFunFour = async() => {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x8/");
  var response = await httpGet(url);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  //var data = response.split("/");
  var htmlresp = "<b>System Usage</b><hr class='hru hrusm'>CPU : " + response['cpu'] + "%<br>RAM : " + response['ram'] + "%";

  document.getElementById("cpu").innerHTML = htmlresp;
  setTimeout(() => {
    hcFunFour();
  }, 1000)
}

hcFunFive = async() => {

  url = ngUrl.concat("x9/");
  var response = await httpGet(url);
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  window['head'] = parseFloat(response['msg']);
  //console.log(head);
  //console.log(typeof window['head']);
  setTimeout(() => {
    hcFunFive();
  }, 1000)

}


setTimeout(function() {
  hcFunOne();
  hcFunTwo();
  hcFunThree();
  hcFunFour();
  hcFunFive();
}, 500);

// ------MAP WORK-----


var map;
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
  var haightAshbury = {
    lat: window.map_lat,
    lng: window.map_lon
  };


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: haightAshbury,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });



  setInterval(function() {


    var lats = window.map_lat;
    var lngs = window.map_lon;
    map.setCenter({
      lat: lats,
      lng: lngs
    });


    var temp2 = {
      lat: lats,
      lng: lngs


    }
    /
    addMarker(temp2);

    console.log(head);

  }, 2000);


  addMarker(haightAshbury);
}


function addMarker(location) {
  setMapOnAll(null);



  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,

    icon: {
      path: "M0 0 L0 25 L 25 0 L 0 0",
      fillColor: '#CC0000',
      fillOpacity: .8,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      strokeWeight: 1.5,
      scale: 1.3,
      rotation: 45 + head,


    }
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}


function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}


initMap();
```

Comment: I fail to see the point in having sync get and async code. Use Fetch asynchronously. Also DRY (Don't repeat yourself), Use an array and loop. And why interval???

Comment: In that way it should also become unresponsive in localhost but it works fine in localhost

Comment: Browsers limit how many requests can go through a page concurrently. Adding in network latency will delay the request and responses, thus clogging up the processing for the page as each request gets added to the queue. Eventually this is going to cause the UI to freeze up and could cause the Javascript engine and/or browser to stop functioning properly as it tries to get a handle on the mess.

Comment: @daddygames  how to solve this this issue ? It will be a great help

Comment: If you really need to have near-constant communication with the server like this, then WebSocket or something similar would probably be the recommended solution. You may find this article helpful -> https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b

Comment: I will go through the article .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are making too many http requests per second.I think you should consider using WebSocket instead.